# transmission electron microscope beam divergence (limits on resolving power)

Tags: electrons, lenses

I have learnt about TEM recently and have a few questions.

I've searched all across the internet but can't find the answer to whether or net electrons in the beam will repel each other thus diverge reducing the resolving power.

I also understand that lens aberration due to electrons moving at varying speeds due to thermionic emission affects resolution.

I would like to know to what extent these affect resolution and if there are any other factors which affect the maximum resolution of the TEM and how significant are they.

Comment: Cranking through the number on beam current and electron velocity will show you that on average about one electron is in the column at once. So, no, electrons in the beam aren't seeing other electrons in the beam pretty much at all. There is some aberration due to the energy spread, which is reduced by choosing a LaB6 filament that has a low energy spread compared with tungsten.